# PullToResharp Custom ListView Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin

Hi I want to add pull to refresh on my apps using this component [PullToResharp](http://components.xamarin.com/view/pulltorefresharp), The project is great but im having problem adding custom listview in fragment, does anyone here done this before help me resolve it, thanks.
here is the code

- fragment

`namespace ListViewPullToRefresh.Fragments
{
    public class SampleListFragment : SupportListFragment
    {
        private IPullToRefresharpView _ptrView;`

```
    private List<TableItem> _itemHeading = new List<TableItem>();


    public SampleListFragment() : base()
    {
    }
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.nav, null, false);
    }

    public override void OnViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);

        _itemHeading.Add(new TableItem(){Heading = "Ivan", Subheading = "Guinto"});
        _itemHeading.Add(new TableItem(){Heading = "Jonathan", Subheading = "Guinto"});
        _itemHeading.Add(new TableItem(){Heading = "Keneth", Subheading = "Guinto"});

        if (_ptrView == null && ListView is IPullToRefresharpView)
        {
            _ptrView = (IPullToRefresharpView)ListView;
            _ptrView.RefreshActivated += ptr_view_RefreshActivated;
        }
        ListView.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, _itemHeading);
    }

    private void ptr_view_RefreshActivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        View.PostDelayed(() =>
        {
            if (_ptrView != null)
            {
                _ptrView.OnRefreshCompleted();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    public override void OnDestroyView()
    {
        if (_ptrView != null)
        {
            _ptrView.RefreshActivated -= ptr_view_RefreshActivated;
            _ptrView = null;
        }
        base.OnDestroyView();
    }

    public override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        ListView.ItemClick += ListView_ItemClick;
    }

    public override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        ListView.ItemClick -= ListView_ItemClick;
    }

    void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Activity,e.Position+ " Clicked",ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

- HomeScreenAdapter.cs

  `public class HomeScreenAdapter :BaseAdapter<TableItem>
  {`
     `public HomeScreenAdapter(Activity content, List<TableItem> items)
      {
          _content = content;
          _items = items;
      }`

  ```
  public override long GetItemId(int position)
  {
      return position;
  }

  public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
      var item = _items[position];

      var view = convertView;
      if (view == null)
          view = _content.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomView, null);
      view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text1).Text = item.Heading;
      view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text2).Text = item.Subheading;

      return view;
  }

  public override int Count
  {
      get { return _items.Count; }
  }

  public override TableItem this[int position]
  {
      get { return _items[position]; }
  }
  ```

  }
  }

im getting this error

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'ListViewPullToRefresh.HomeScreenAdapter.HomeScreenAdapter(Android.App.Activity, System.Collections.Generic.List)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users******\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ListViewPullToRefresh\ListViewPullToRefresh\Fragments\SampleListFragment.cs   43  32  ListViewPullToRefresh
>
> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ListViewPullToRefresh.Fragments.SampleListFragment' to 'Android.App.Activity'  C:\Users****\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ListViewPullToRefresh\ListViewPullToRefresh\Fragments\SampleListFragment.cs 43  54  ListViewPullToRefresh

when i putting my custom adapter to the fragment, i get the error here `ListView.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, _itemHeading);` and here `public HomeScreenAdapter(Activity content, List<TableItem> items)
    {
        _content = content;
        _items = items;
    }`

Comment: Could you share with us code that you have tried already? More details please

Comment: hi , i added some code that i wrote, hope u can help me

Comment: ok sorry to bother u i just solve it my self by changing the `activity` to `fragmentActivity`